# SSIS PrimeOutput Error?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have an SSIS job that has been running for over a year with no issue. The job takes a data set from a select statement in an oracle db and transfers the result to a table on a SQL Server 2005 instance.

As of this morning, we receive the following error message:

Error: 2010-05-26 05:06:47.71     Code: 0xC02090F5     Source: [job_name] DataReader Source [793]     Description: The component "DataReader Source" (793) was unable to process the data.  End Error  Error: 2010-05-26 05:06:47.71     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: job_name      Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "DataReader Source" (793) returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2010-05-26 05:06:47.71     Code: 0xC0047021     Source: P...  The package execution fa...  The step failed.

Does anyone know what a root cause might be?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a pretty ambiguous error. Has there been any recent tbl schema changes to your Oracle tbl?

Comment: No. This schema has been static for > 6 months.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information
>   about the failure.

Did you look for other more specific error messages?

Are you logging errors or steps as they run? If so did you look in the logging table? If you aren't logging in you SSIS package, I'd set that up as part of this fix, it will make it immeasurably earier to find the problem.

Things I would consider:
schema changes, permissions changes, any recent software, operating systems updates to the servers involved, data mismatches (the first time perhaps that the Oracle table held data that couldn't be inserted into the SQL table - check columns that don;t directly match first, string data that might get truncated, dates stored as strings that need to convert to datetime, etc.).

Comment: The logging showed that the process was running, then was killed. We broke apart the complex query that was pulling thew data from Oracle, and it turned out to be a data type mismatch. The error wasn't bubbling up and showing any kind of useful message. It was just failing silently during the data transfer.

Comment: Ours was a schema change - the original CSV had a stray blank column at the end of the CSV file, while the new data didn't have this extra column. So we just added this blank column for SSIS - "Column 15" in this case - and it now works.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue loading data and as in your case found the error too general so I checked the option to "Include Step Output in History" which can be found on the Advanced Options of the SQL Server Job Step. This helped me tremendously since the error was a lot more helpful and helped me determine that the problem was on the source. Hope that helps you debug.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error because a flat file with no column names was received, but the import job expected the first row to have column names.  Once the column names were added, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to us when a column is removed from the csv.