# VS 2015 Executing SSIS Package Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package that when I run them from within VS 2015 Update 3, fails on a step. I asked another developer to try running the package on his machine, and it works fine on his machine. He also has VS 2015 update 3.

> [name of step] Error: The [name of step] was unable to process the data. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on [name of step] returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I have tried repairing VS2015, but the issue still happens.

Comment: what is the `PrimeOutput` method? Looks like a load error

Comment: From what i've seen on stackoverflow, Primeoutput is part of a generic and unfortunately detail lacking error message that can occur in SSIS.

Comment: Do you have the same version of SSDT?

Comment: yes. but Im installing ssdt again to see if that helps

Comment: reinstalling it didnt help - same error

Comment: Have you seen this already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912860/ssis-primeoutput-error

Comment: Yes, I've seen that but it didnt help - someone where I work is suggesting that it is some sort of permission error because the person who originally created the package can open and run it.